# What is this kind of plot and how do I change its color

Tags: r, plot

I really like taking advantage of the 120+ plotting methods of base R `plot` function, throwing at it random object and checking what comes out.

This time, I just sent a basic `data.frame` with one `factor`variable.  I like the plot that came out, but I couldn't manage to change its color.

To make the plot:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

dd <- data.frame(FF = cut(runif(1000,0,100), seq(0,100,10)),
                 XX = rnorm(1000, 10, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(FF) %>% 
  summarize(XX=mean(XX))
```

Plotting it with `plot(dd)` gives:

[image]

I want the bars to be an other color than black.  I tried the obvious `plot(dd, col="red")` but it doesn't do anything.  Same thing with `fg` or `bg`, which I tried also.

I looked at `?plot.data.frame` and `?plot.factor` but didn't see any hint on how to change the color.  What actual function is building this plot, how do we call it and how to change the colors on it?

Comment: Generating something random till you like the output is not exactly the best process for deriving insight from data or telling the truth with data.

Comment: @hrbrmstr.  ???  My example is a reproducible example, not my real data!  I don't get your comment, it isn't related to the question.  With eipi10's answer, I've been able to change the colors of my plot with my REAL data and it looks great, there is no random there!

Comment: _"I really like taking advantage of the 120+ plotting methods of base R plot function, throwing at it random object and checking what comes out."_ Just letting others know that's not a great practice for real data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `plot` is trying to make a boxplot, but since there's only one value per category, you're getting a single horizontal line. `border="red"` will change the color to red. If you run `x = plot(dd)` and then inspect `x`, you'll see it's a list in which the first element contains the boxplot stats.

`plot` is a "generic" function that "dispatches" different actual plotting functions (called "methods"), depending on what type of object you provide to `plot`. In this case, you have a categorical x-axis variable, so `plot` dispatches a "method" that produces a boxplot.

To see what specific functions `plot` can call, run `methods(plot)`. I haven't checked, but I suspect the `plot.data.frame` function ends up calling a function that produces a boxplot when the x variable is categorical and the y variable is numeric (run `graphics:::plot.data.frame(dd)`, to see this).

If you run `plot` before summarizing, you can see the boxplot appear:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
dd <- data.frame(FF = cut(runif(1000,0,100), seq(0,100,10)),
                 XX = rnorm(1000, 10, 2))

plot(dd, border="red")
```

[image]

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(FF) %>% 
  summarize(XX=mean(XX)) %>% 
  plot(border="red")
```

[image]

Comment: In french we say: "oeil de lynx"!  Thanks, it's exactly that!